# Create a method not limited by subscriptions

Tags: meteor

I've created a method that checks if an email already has an account:

```
insertGroupMember: function(eventId, memberDetails) {
    var memberAccount = Meteor.users.findOne({'emails.address': memberDetails.email});

        if (memberAccount) {
            console.log('Existing User')
        } else {
            console.log('Create User')
        }
}
```

But will only receive a result when I am subscribed to a publication with all users.emails. How can I achieve the same results without having to publish everyone's email? I think thats kind of bad for security/privacy, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct - you don't want to publish all of the users to the client just to accomplish this. The best solution is to create a [method](http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header) defined only on the server, and then call it from the client.

#### server/methods.js

```js
Meteor.methods({
  insertGroupMember: function(eventId, memberDetails) {
    ...
  }
});
```

#### client/someTemplate.js

```js
Meteor.call('insertGroupMember', eventId, memberDetails, function (err, result){
  ... 
});
```